# Canvas from storage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a project which I’m about to look into and it involves users saving designs they’ve made on canvas and at a later date being able to edit them if needed.

I’ve looked around the web and all I can find is saving the dataURL which looks like a base64 version of the Canvas.

If this is right, how would the editing work in the future? I would of thought the objects on the canvas were stored in a database as JSON and parsed but I can see how you would do that with the dataURL

Apologies for the lack of code I’m just looking for some advice.

Comment: Try it. Write a canvas dataUrl to `localstorage`, then retrieve it and create a new canvas using it. Let us know what happens.

Comment: Why should you save the canvas as dataURL? If you have all the drawing operations needed to redraw it, then yes store these drawing operations in JSON.

Comment: hmm, I'm going to look at this today - thanks guys